# Issue featuring 2 posts on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, posts

I am trying to feature 2 posts on the homepage of a recruitment site and when there are no posts I want to display a message on the home page stating "There are currently no opportunities open."

I have managed to do one or the other however cannot get both to function together.

UPDATE: I have now got the message to display if there are no posts, however the homepage no longer features two posts it only features one....

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=2' ); ?>
<?php if ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>


<div class="block-halves exec-ops" ><!--id="b-10"-->

<span class="block-content">     



<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_field('post_title');?></a></h3>
<span class="btm"> 

<p class="job-title"><?php the_field('job_title');?></p>
<p><?php echo excerpt(22); ?></p>
<p><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>"><?php the_field('cta_button_home');?></a></p>            


</span> 


</span>

</div>     

<?php else: ?>      
<div class="block-halves exec-ops" ><!--display if no posts available-->

<span class="block-content">     



<h3>There are currently no opportunities open</h3>
<span class="btm">

<p class="job-title">Submit Your CV</p>
<p>We actively search for suitable roles and select the top candidates from submitted CV's when new opportunities open up.</p>
<p><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(47); ?>">Submit</a></p>            

</span> 


</span>

</div>  


<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata();?>                  




</div><!--flex-row/end-->
```

Comment: You are able to try id with check $the_query is empty or not? Like
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=2' ); ?>
<?php If(!empty $the_query){ ?>
then your code and close Brackets for if loop.

Comment: thanks for the reply - unfortunately this didn't work

Comment: The `post_count` property of the WP_Query object holds the number of posts that were returned, so use that.

Comment: see the update above :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following allows to determine if any posts exist and loop through them if they do:

```
if (!$the_query -> have_posts()):
    echo "no posts";
else:
    while($the_query -> have_posts()): $the_query -> the_post();
        // Your loop code
    endwhile;
endif;
```